# React/Express - Axios get request help needed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

Trying to make an API get request from front-end (React) to back-end (Express/MongoDB) using Axios. If I use Postman to make the request it works fine (you can enter a user ID in the request body and get back an array of objects containing that user ID, which is what I want), but doing it from a front-end built in React doesn't work, I just get an empty array returned. As far as I can tell my API call from the front-end is exactly the same as the one I'm making in Postman! Can anyone shed any light on this?

This is the code making the get request from the front end:

```
   const getActivities = async (currentUser) => {
    const config = {
        crossdomain: true,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: {
            "user": `${currentUser[0].id}`,
        }
        
      
    }
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/activities', config)
    console.log(res)
   dispatch({
        type: GET_ACTIVITIES,
        payload: res.data
   })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
   
   
}
```

And this is the route on the back-end handling this particular request:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const activities = await Activities.find({ user: req.body.user }).sort({ date: -1 })
    if (!activities) {
        res.json({msg: "Nothing found. Go forth and exercise!" })
    }  
   
    res.json(activities).send()
} catch (err) {
    res.send(err.message)
}
```

})

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send a request body with **GET** method see [API AXIOS](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) only for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE , and 'PATCH'.

for example if you want to keep a GET method use params

```
// React

const config = {
   crossdomain: true,
   headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
   },
   params: {
     user: `${currentUser[0].id}`,
   }
}

try {
 const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/activities',config)
 console.log(res.data)
}catch(err){
 ...
}

// Express

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.user)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's done it! Had to use req.query instead of req.params in the router in the end but it's working.

Comment: Great to go further take a look at axios.create() for pass config any time